# Need help on multiple text files in a path to insert in database

Tags: c#

I have two text files in my path, any idea why only one text file inserts into my database?
[image]

> After running the application it stops and return an
>   'System.NullReferenceException'
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

This is the code.

```
try
{
    var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\K\Desktop\New folder", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                select new
                {
                    File = file,
                    Line = line
                };

    foreach (var f in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", f.File, f.Line);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f.File))
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(f.File).SkipWhile(x => !x.Contains("[Start]")))
          {

              string readLine;
              do
              {
                  readLine = sr.ReadLine();
                  string[] readLineSplit = readLine.Split('|');

                  if(readLineSplit.Length > 1)
                  {
                      using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"server=localhost;database=test;uid=root;pwd=pw;"))
                      {
                          con.Open();
                          MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Products(Product_Name, Product_Price, QTY) VALUES (@Product_Name, @Product_Price, @QTY)", con);
                          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Name", readLineSplit[0].ToString());
                          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Price", readLineSplit[1].ToString());
                          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTY", readLineSplit[2]);
                          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                      }
                  }


                          } while (!sr.EndOfStream);
                      }
```

Comment: On which line exactly? And [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: this line string[] readLineSplit = readLine.Split('|');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be something like this: not testest ´cause no mysql here and to less time:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\K\Desktop\New folder", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"server=localhost;database=test;uid=root;pwd=pw;"))
{
    con.Open(); // new Position of con.Open()
    foreach (var f in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(f);
        bool processRecord = false;

        foreach (string line in Lines)
        {
            if (!processRecord)
            {
                if (Lines.Contains("[Start]"))
                {
                    processRecord = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (Lines.Contains("[End]"))
            {
                processRecord = false;
                continue;
            }
            if (processRecord)
            {
                string[] readLineSplit = line.Split('|');

                if (readLineSplit.Length > 1)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Products(Product_Name, Product_Price, QTY) VALUES (@Product_Name, @Product_Price, @QTY)", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Name", readLineSplit[0]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Price", readLineSplit[1]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTY", readLineSplit[2]);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, made a mistake ... now complete.

**EDIT:** NOW complete!

**EDIT:** [End] condition added.

**EDIT:** Moved con.Open() to be called just once.

**EDIT:** Changed small typo and removed the faulty File Enumeration

Comment: thanks this works! but it inserts the two text files multiple times into the database, i have a [end] tag also how can i stop inserting if it reads that line?

Comment: please explain: Show me the datafile Content - or maybe my new check for process record is corret, the first one was erroneous.

Comment: this is the text file 

text here,text here, text here.
text here, text here, text here.
text here, text here, text here.
text here, text here, text here.
text here,  text here, text here.
[Start]
"Donuts"|"30"|"54"
"Egg"|"20"|"25"
"Apple"|"15"|"18"
"Orange"|"20"|"15"
"Pineapple"|"30"|"29"
[End]

Comment: See the code now - I made a small change **:-)** - moved con.Open() to the place where it belongs - and please don´t forget to vote!

Comment: nice! :) but look it still inserting multiple records. this is the image: http://i.imgur.com/lXm526Y.jpg?1

Comment: First: Are you sure you copied my code correct? There are two nested loops: The outer loop over the files, the inner loop over all lines to process. If date are doubled, there is maybe a problem with your date files.Just to be sure: you delete the old inserted data? please provide the textfiles (in your post, as code so we can read it).

Comment: yes, i even drop then recreated the table then run the program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74322/discussion-between-thomas-krojer-and-kevin-rodriguez).